# How to run batch file automatically and ignore windows UAC policy

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a web application installed on server that has PCI complaint policy, I can't do almost  anything unless I press ctrl-alt-end, I have an external tool on server l that launches a batch file which restarts a specific application service, but this not doable due to UAC policy, is there a way to make it doable? 
Please note that there is no way to disable UAC.

Comment: If you have admin credentials (user and password) you can invoke the bat file through schtasks , or you can try to set `set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker` somewhere - this prevents UAC prompt in some situations (but does not grant you admin access)

Comment: As @npocmaka said, you can't simply bypass UAC, but if you can get administrator access at least once, then you can create a task that runs elevated or as a privileged system account. From then on the task can be run via `schtasks /run /tn [task name]`. If you need to synchronize on it you can use `waitfor.exe signal` to wait for a signal that the batch sets via `waitfor.exe /si signal`.

Comment: Are you sure UAC is the problem?  Sounds more like group policy to me, e.g., access to the command interpreter might have been disabled.  Have you discussed the issue with the server administrators?